# Getting SUM and JOIN to cooperate in a specific query

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck with a certain query, it seems to be simple but it seems I might have to split it in different ways to get it to accomplish what I want to do. I tried combining, recombining and I could use some guidance.

Here's a sample table, the output and expected output.

#### Shop_Table

```
shop_id |     item_type  | date

   1          soaps         2000-01-01
   2          food          2000-01-02
   3          appliances    2000-01-03
   4          electronics   2000-01-10
   5          furniture     2000-01-13
   6          misc.         2000-01-15
```

#### Instance_Table

```
instanceid|    shop_id    | firstname | lastname | number_of_items

   11            3            jane        doe          2
   22            2            jane        doe          3
   33            1            jane        doe          5
   44            4            jane        doe          6
   55            6            jane        doe          1
   66            5            jane        doe          2
```

#### The Query

```
SELECT 
IF
( 
    Shop_Table.item_type
    IN
        (
            'soaps',
            'food'
         ),
    'indexpensives',
    Shop_Table.item_type
), 
COALESCE(SUM(Person.number_of_items), 0) AS item_sum
FROM Shop_Table

INNER JOIN Instance_Table AS Instance
ON Instance.shop_id = Shop_Table.shop_id
AND Instance.firstname =  'jane'
AND Instance.lastname =  'doe'
AND Shop_Table.date BETWEEN DATE(  '2000-01-01' ) AND DATE(  '2000-01-03' )

GROUP BY Shop_Table.item_type
```

Which returns:

```
  item_type     |     item_sum

indexpensives   |        8
appliances      |        2
```

#### Output

Which is great so far, and is where I'm stuck. What I really want is the following output:

#### Expected Output

```
  item_type     |     item_sum

inexpensives    |        8
appliances      |        2
electronics     |        0
furniture       |        0
misc.           |        0
```

I think it's pretty straight forward what I want to do. What's making it a little tough is that it has a little bit of everything.

- Grouping and combining sum results (soaps and food into one result)
- Returning 0 for the rest of the item types when the date is outside the specified range.

#### Update:

Turned out a little more complicated than I thought, but it's what I wanted. Thank you everyone for helping out.

```
SELECT 
IF
( 
    Shop_Table.item_type
    IN
        (
            'soaps',
            'food'
         ),
    'inexpensives',
    Shop_Table.item_type
), 
COALESCE(SUM(Person.number_of_items), 0) AS item_sum
FROM Shop_Table
LEFT OUTER JOIN Instance_Table AS Instance
ON Instance.shop_id = Shop_Table.shop_id
AND Instance.firstname =  'jane'
AND Instance.lastname =  'doe'
AND Shop_Table.date BETWEEN DATE(  '2000-01-01' ) AND DATE(  '2000-01-03' )
GROUP BY IF
( 
    Shop_Table.item_type
    IN
        (
            'soaps',
            'food'
         ),
    'inexpensives',
    Shop_Table.item_type
)
```

Comment: you'll want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Will also need to move `AND Shop_Table.date ...` criteria to `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Actually, if I use `WHERE` it won't give me the whole list of the column `item_type`, even with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Tek, okay, so you do really only want to join on Shop_Table records within a certain date range. Sorry. My mistake. I thought you wanted to apply the date range to the entire result set.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I want it to SUM within a specific date range BUT also return all the item types. At the same time SUM returns zero to any `item_type` outside the date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to this and you should get the totals you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
IF
( 
    Shop_Table.item_type
    IN
        (
            'soaps',
            'food'
         ),
    'indexpensives',
    Shop_Table.item_type
), 
SUM(Person.number_of_items) AS item_sum
FROM Shop_Table

LEFT OUTER JOIN Instance_Table AS Instance
ON Instance.shop_id = Shop_Table.shop_id
AND Instance.firstname =  'jane'
AND Instance.lastname =  'doe'
AND Shop_Table.date BETWEEN DATE(  '2000-01-01' ) AND DATE(  '2000-01-03' )

GROUP BY Shop_Table.item_type
```

**Explanation**
An outer join will select all rows from one table and matching rows from another. So, a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will select all rows from the table on the left side of the join (Shop_Table in this case) and matching rows from the table on the right side of the join (Instance_Table in this case).

Comment: It works beautifully! Turns out I also had a `WHERE` instead of an `AND` before `Shop_Table.date`. Doh! The only problem I'm having now is that the IF is changing the `soaps` and `food` to `inexpensive` BUT it's not combining the result of the two. I'm getting duplicate `inexpensives` results.

Comment: @Tek, simply copy the `IF` statement verbatim into the `GROUP BY` clause like `GROUP BY IF(...`.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that before and it didn't work. My goodness, thank you! And since you were the first to answer, I'll accept this as the accepted question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all replace your `inner join` with a `left join` and then make sure you `coalesce` the `sum` with a 0, like this:

```
SELECT 
IF
( 
    Shop_Table.item_type
    IN
        (
            'soaps',
            'food'
         ),
    'indexpensives',
    Shop_Table.item_type
), 
COALESCE(SUM(Person.number_of_items), 0) AS item_sum
FROM Shop_Table
LEFT JOIN Instance_Table AS Instance
ON Instance.shop_id = Shop_Table.shop_id
AND Instance.firstname =  'jane'
AND Instance.lastname =  'doe'
AND Shop_Table.date BETWEEN DATE(  '2000-01-01' ) AND DATE(  '2000-01-03' )
GROUP BY Shop_Table.item_type
```

**Edit:**

After the requirement changes, this should be the final query:

```
SELECT 
IF
( 
    Shop_Table.item_type
    IN
        (
            'soaps',
            'food'
         ),
    'inexpensives',
    Shop_Table.item_type
) as FinalType, 
COALESCE(SUM(Person.number_of_items), 0) AS item_sum
FROM Shop_Table
LEFT OUTER JOIN Instance_Table AS Instance
ON Instance.shop_id = Shop_Table.shop_id
AND Instance.firstname =  'jane'
AND Instance.lastname =  'doe'
AND Shop_Table.date BETWEEN DATE(  '2000-01-01' ) AND DATE(  '2000-01-03' )
GROUP BY FinalType
```

Comment: Just name the calculated field in the `IF` and group by that field